# Deactivating PHP error logging

Tags: php, logging, compiler-errors, xampp, reporting

I just noticed that all of the PHP errors I get in XAMPP are stored in a log, which has a size of 500 MB already. I now want to deactivate logging, without actually stopping the reporting while execution. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the errors?

Comment: I still want errors to be displayed, of course. I just don't want them to be stored in a log file anymore.

Comment: Just purge the file periodically, then. One day you'll be glad it's there. You can just delete it, it'll be recreated when you produce new errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your php file

```
ini_set('log_errors', 'off');
```

or in your PHP.ini:

```
log_errors = off
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. Is there also a way to deactivate it completely, like a flag in some config file?

Comment: ini_set('display_errors','Off');

Comment: I meant just the logging, and not deactivating it in my code, but in some file that came with Xampp, like httpd.conf or something like that. I'm sure somewhere in there is a flag for that, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: edit \YourPathTo\xampp\php\php.ini and set log_errors = off

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```